# java application properties file in between standalone jar and services which use it

Tags: java, spring-boot, embedded-resource, properties-file

Standalone sprint boot jar is implemented a service call. This jar has a defined host per each environment.

src/main/resources

For example : 
File named "application-PreProduction.properties" , contains : service.client.host=http://svc.pp.com

Another application is a service which uses this standalone jar among other services which use it.
This service has also its properties files since it also call other services.

It seems the service application properties files override the standalone jar properties files although the content is different. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Load properties from file with a different name, using `@PropertySource`.

Comment: Can we assume this is a Spring Boot application? You don't say it anywhere, so if it is, please tag it with [tag:spring-boot]

Answer (score 0):

If you are building a service over another, they should communicate with each other via a call back request not via dependency.

in another word they both should exist in the same level not as a impeded modules.